# lilo, install in target-mbr from another system

Tags: linux, boot

I have a embedded system (short ES) on a cf-card (short CFC). 
I plugged the CFC into the cardreader of my notebook.

Sure the devices of my notebook are not the same then in the ES.

Now the mainboard of the changed and the CF-card is connected to another controler (other /dev/hdX).
So I am not able to boot the ES from the CFC, because of other kernel parameters (hdd device).

I mounted the CFC on the notebook and changed the lilo.conf but now I am not able to reinstall the new config into the CFCs MBR.

I tried parameter -M but lilo checks that the device-names in the lilo.conf on the CFC are not the same that on my notebook.

e.g. I try to install on /dev/sdc (the CFC on my notebook) but the root-parameter in lilo.conf is (dev/hda) because the system is running on the ES, not my notebook.

So, how can I tell lilo to install in a MBR with parameters of my target system (ES)??

Answer (score 1):

```
mount -o bind /sys $yourmount/sys
mount -o bind /proc $yourmount/dev
mount -o bind /proc $yourmount/proc
chroot /$yourmount /bin/sh
lilo
```

And it should work, if not - check the path to disc device ( /dev/hda /dev/sda etc ) as the system you booted from might use a different device name for that particular disk.
For example:

```
root="LABEL=MyDisk"
```

Or use UUID instead of LABEL (man lilo.conf).